# Logic, writing proof

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, self-learning

> i)Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. Prove that if $x\neq 0$,
>   then if $y=\frac{3x^2+2y}{x^2+2}$ then $y=3$
>
> ii)Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. Prove that if
>   $x^2y=2x+y$, then if $y\neq 0$ then $x\neq 0$

What I did is

i)Suppose that $y\neq3\Rightarrow \frac{3x^2+2y}{x^2+2}\neq 3\Leftrightarrow 3x^2+2y\neq 3x^2+6\Rightarrow y=3$ which is a contradition then if $y=\frac{3x^2+2y}{x^2+2}$ then $y=3$

Is this right? I need to make some consideration about $x$?

ii)Suppose that $y=0$ and $x=0$ thus $x^2+y\neq2x+y\Leftrightarrow 0\neq0$, which is a contradition then $x^2y=2x+y$, then if $y\neq 0$ then $x\neq 0$

Comment: It is usually discouraged to use $\not=$ like an $=$ in a proof and perform the same steps to both sides.  If you're not careful, you can turn a $\not=$ into an $=$.

Comment: It would be easier in $(i)$ to start with your assumptions that $x\not=0$ and $y=\frac{3x^2+2y}{x^2+2}$ and try to conclude that $y=3$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I tried that way because the topic in the book talks about proof by contradiction

Comment: If you're doing contradiction, then you should still assume $y=\frac{3x^2+2y}{x^2+2}$, but you should also assume $y\not=3$.  (Assuming the hypothesis and the negation of the conclusion).

Comment: The first is right, though I would certainly not use that style of argument. The second has incorrect logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**i)**  Given $$y=\frac{3x^2+2y}{x^2+2}$$
cross multiplying we have,
$$y(x^2+2)=3x^2+2y$$
$$\implies yx^2+2y=3x^2+2y$$
canceling $2y$ in both side we have,
$$yx^2=3x^2$$
Since $x\neq 0 \implies x^2\neq0$ So dividing both side by x^2, we have 
$$y=3$$

**ii)** On contrary suppose that $x=0$ then we have $x^2=0$ so $$0\cdot y=2\cdot 0 +y$$
$$\implies y=0$$
Which is a contradiction since given that $y\neq 0$

Answer (score 1):

For ii), a better starting approach is to assume that $y=0$ and $x \neq 0$. You are trying to find a contradiction.

Then for the left hand side you would have:

$$ x^2 y = x^2 (0) = 0$$

On the right hand side:

$$ 2x + y = 2x + 0  = 2x \neq 0 \text{$\qquad$ by assumption that $x \neq 0$}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP has stated that contradiction is needed, here's another answer.

Consider the statement: If $x\not=0$, then if $y=\frac{3x^2+2y}{x^2+2}$ then $y=3$.

The hypothesis is $x\not=0$ and the conclusion is if $y=\frac{3x^2+2y}{x^2+2}$ then $y=3$

To prove this by contradiction, you need to assume the hypothesis and the negation of the conclusion.  The negation of the conclusion is the negation of an if-then statement.  Since $A\rightarrow B\equiv \neg A\vee B$, its negation is $A\wedge \neg B$.

Therefore, you should assume $x\not=0$, $y=\frac{3x^2+2y}{x^2+2}$, and $y\not=3$ and try to find a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch for $(i)$:  Suppose $x\not=0$ and $y=\frac{3x^2+2y}{x^2+2}$.

1) Observe $x^2+2$ is never zero (must be proven).

2) Multiply both sides by $x^2+2$ to get $yx^2+2y=3x^2+2y$.

3) Subtract $2y$ from both sides to get $yx^2=3x^2$.

4) Divide both sides by $x^2$ (which you can do because $x\not=0$, here is where we use that assumption - you might need to prove that $x^2\not=0$ if you want to be pedantic).

5) You are left with $y=3$.

Note: You could, alternately at step $4$, subtract $3x^2$ from both sides and factor to get $x^2(y-3)=0$.  Since a product equals zero, one of the factors is zero, but since $x\not=0$, $y-3=0$ or $y=3$.